# Cognito Forms: Converting form to PDF

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to print or save in PDF format -- the form entries with all the file attachments (uploaded by the clients) and the signature that the applicants has submitted. Please advise how. Exporting to excel does not serve my purpose. I need help urgently on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a PDF of your entry on the Entries page using the 'Create Document' feature. The Default PDF options will not include uploaded files. You would have to set up a custom document merge to include images in the created PDF.